# how to deserialize the response via rest assured and Java

Tags: java, rest-assured, jackson-databind

I'm sending a post request for the Login API of Demoblaze Website https://www.demoblaze.com/. I've searched over the internet about their official API documentation, and have found the postman collection that is used for this.

The login API specs found in postman:

endpoint: https://api.demoblaze.com/login

payload:

```
{
   "username": "horacioss1",
    "password": "1234567890"
}
```

when I send the request I get the following response:

```
"Auth_token: aG9yYWNpb3NzMTE2OTc2NDM="
```

The question here is how can I create a POJO class for the following response:

```
"Auth_token: aG9yYWNpb3NzMTE2OTc2NDM="
```

as it's just a string not a key-value pair.

Comment: Looks like a key-value pair to me, with the colon separating key and value. I don't understand what you are asking. It would be helpful to add your code as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a String, you cannot use default deserialization in Rest-Assured. To get token, just split String and get it.

```java
String res = given()...asString();
String token = res.split(" ")[1];
System.out.println("token);
//aG9yYWNpb3NzMTE2OTc2NDM=
```

if you want to do something like POJO (it's little bit over skill), then here you are:

```java
@Test
void q77275023() {
    String res = given()...asString();
    String token = new Auth(res).getAuthToken();
    System.out.println("token = " + token);
}

static class Auth {
    private String authToken;

    public Auth(String res) {
        String value = res.split(" ")[1];
        this.authToken = value;
    }

    public String getAuthToken() {
        return authToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot lucas I've already used asString() to retrieve the response as a string, and then asserted that the response contains("Auth_token"). And it worked successfully.